# Is it possible to get access to custom columns for a document library in the office desktop applications (Word, Excel) search functionality?

Tags: document-library, search, search-results, enterprise-search, office

Is it possible to get access to custom columns for a document library in the office desktop applications (Word, Excel) search functionality?
The client does not want the users to access documents from the web portal but only create, open or edit from the desktop applications (Word, Excel, PowerPoint etc.)

While we can search for the files in the Open dialog, can this search get access to the custom columns to filter the results?